# нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x68D8FB46. С++

Tags: c++, функции, объявление

Вот надо написать программу для инженерного калькулятора. Написал пока функции умножения и перевода в другую сс. Проблема в том что после того как ввел числа и выбрал 3 пункт(умножение) то выдает нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x68D8FB46.

В чем ошибка подскажите пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

string ToBin1(string st1, int ss11);
string ToBin2(string st1, int ss12);
int ToDec(string r);
//int Summ(string bin1, string bin2);
//int Diff(string bin1, string bin2);
void Mult(string bin1, string bin2);
//int Chas(string bin1, string bin2);
//int Comp(string bin1, string bin2);


int main(string bin1, string bin2)
{
    int  ss11, ss12;
    string st1, st2;
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");//руссификатор

    int N,action=0;//Переменные целого типа

        cout << "Введите первое число и его систему счисления: " << endl;
        cin >> st1 >> ss11;
        cout << ToBin1(st1,ss11) << endl;

        cout << "Введите второе число: " << endl;
        cin >> st2 >> ss12;
        cout << ToBin2(st2,ss12) << endl;



        cout<<"------------------------Menu--------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"Выберите действие: "<<endl;
        cout<<"1)Сложить числа "<<endl;
        cout<<"2)Вычесть числа "<<endl;
        cout<<"3)Умножить числа "<<endl;
        cout<<"4)Разделить числа "<<endl;
        cout<<"5)Сравнить числа "<<endl;
        cout<<"6)Выход из программы"<<endl;
        cout<<"------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"Ваш выбор :";//Запрос выбора пункта меню
        cin>>action;//Ввод выбора
        system ("cls");//очистка консоли
        switch (action) 
        {
        //case 1: Summ(bin1, bin2); break;
        //case 2: Diff(bin1, bin2); break;
        case 3: Mult(bin1, bin2); break;
        //case 4: Chas(bin1, bin2); break;
        //case 5: Comp(bin1, bin2); break;
        case 6: exit(0); break;
        }
    return 0;
}

string ToBin1(string st1, int ss11)
{

    int i, k, p, dec;
    string bin1;
    string digits[16] = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
    string digits1 = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";


    for (size_t i = 0; i < st1.length(); i++)
    {
        size_t pos = digits1.find(tolower(st1[i]));
        if (pos == string::npos || pos >= ss11)
        {
            cerr << "Wrong symbol in value " << st1 << endl;
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    dec = 0;
    p = st1.length() - 1;


    for (i = 0; p >= 0; i++, p--)
        {
        k = toupper(st1[i]);
        dec += ( (k>='A') ? 10+k-'A' : k-'0') * pow(ss11,p);
        } 

    do 
        { 
        bin1.insert(0, digits[dec % 2]); 
        dec /= 2; 
        } while (dec != 0); 


    return bin1;

}


string ToBin2(string st2, int ss12)
{

    int i, k, p, dec;
    string bin2;
    string digits[16] = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
    string digits1 = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";


    for (size_t i = 0; i < st2.length(); i++)
    {
        size_t pos = digits1.find(tolower(st2[i]));
        if (pos == string::npos || pos >= ss12)
        {
            cerr << "Wrong symbol in value " << st2 << endl;
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    dec = 0;
    p = st2.length() - 1;


    for (i = 0; p >= 0; i++, p--)
        {
        k = toupper(st2[i]);
        dec += ( (k>='A') ? 10+k-'A' : k-'0') * pow(ss12,p);
        } 

    do 
        { 
        bin2.insert(0, digits[dec % 2]); 
        dec /= 2; 
        } while (dec != 0); 


        return bin2;

}

int ToDec(string r)
{
    int dec, p, k;
    dec = 0;
    p = r.length() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; p >= 0; i++, p--)
        {
        k = toupper(r[i]);
        dec += ( (k>='A') ? 10+k-'A' : k-'0') * pow(2,p);
        } 
    return dec;
}

void Mult(string bin1, string bin2)
{
    int p, k;
    string r(bin1.length()+bin2.length()-1,'0');

    for (int i = bin1.length()-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = bin2.length()-1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            r[i+j] += (bin1[i] != '0' && bin2[j] != '0');
        }
    }

    for (int i = r.length()-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        r[i-1] += (r[i]-'0')/2;
        r[i] = (r[i]-'0')%2 + '0';
    }

    while(r[0] > '1')
    {
        r = "0" + r;
        r[0] += (r[1]-'0')/2;
        r[1] = (r[1]-'0')%2 + '0';
    }


    cout << endl << "The multiplication of these numbers is: " << ToDec(r) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас некорректное объявление функции `main`

```
int main(string bin1, string bin2)
```

Стандартом C++ не допускается такое объявление, а если некоторый компилятор такое допускает, то это обязательно должно быть описано в документации по компилятору.

Программа имеет неопределенное поведение.

Comment: я убрал это из оббявления но потом пришлось сделать так: case 3: Mult(string bin1,string bin2); break;  И он все равно подчеркивает...

Comment: а вот так можно сделать? Mult(ToBin1(st1,ss11), ToBin2(st2,ss12)) У меня вроде все стало работать....

Comment: @Roman Как перестанет работать, то зададите новый вопрос.:)